# Div with svg background image

Tags: html, css, svg, transparency

I have a div inside a div. And the second one has .svg image as a background and it is transparent, so I can see text that is written on my first div background. I don't want it to be like that and I am not sure what I need to change to remove that transparency. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define background-color property on div 2:

```
background-color:#fff;
```

Source

```css
.img {
  background-image: url('http://www.stupidedia.org/images/a/a3/Gangsta-balz-transparent.svg');
  width: 640px;
  height: 427px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #fff;
}

h1 {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Some text Some text Some text Some text Some text</h1>
  <div class="img">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u. I added some text in paragraph in the second div, text is black, but it has white shadow, it this related to background, or?

Comment: I found it text-shadow: none; I was confused this is not set to none by default. Thanks for the help.